# How to compute makable products from inventory list?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am making an inventory document in excel. We have some different parts in our inventory, that we can assemble to other assembled parts. Like this:

[image]

"Assemble1" consists of Item1 and Item2. Now I want the excel to compute that we can make 3 more Assemble1's (because we only have 3 item1's left). AND I want it to use the "CONSTIST OF" column to do the calculation?

So it has to do a MIN() operation on the stock of ITEM NO. E01 and E02?

Comment: @pnuts no actually not. But thought that I would take one step at the time :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

using the information as layed out in the image above, use the following equation in G7 and copy up or down as required:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,$E$5:$E$7/ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$5:$D$7,F7)),1)
```

now for bonus points you could wrap it in an if statement so that it only checks when its an assembly item otherwise it displays blank such as:

```
=IF(LEFT(D7,1)<>"A","",AGGREGATE(15,6,$E$5:$E$7/ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$5:$D$7,F7)),1))
```